# ERROR: relation "projectfile" does not exist in Activejdbc even if table exists

Tags: activejdbc, javalite

I am getting the following error:

```
org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "projectfile" does not exist
  Position: 25, query: SELECT customer.id FROM projectfile LEFT JOIN project ON projectfile.project_id=project.id LEFT JOIN customer ON project.customer_id=customer.id WHERE (project.activity=6 OR project.activity=1)  AND project.workflowmaxstatus='finish' AND project.workflowminstatus='finish' AND projectfile.type=1 AND projectfile.filename like '%.docx' AND project.startdate > NOW() - interval '2 months' GROUP BY customer.id
```

It seems to complain about a table but I double checked and the table is there in the public schema. I saw there are differet threads open regarding this topic but I couldn't find the solution.

Which is the main cause?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a query used to create this table?

Comment: Here is the query: String query = "SELECT customer.id FROM projectfile " + " LEFT JOIN project ON projectfile.project_id=project.id "
     + " LEFT JOIN customer ON project.customer_id=customer.id" + " WHERE (project.activity=6 OR project.activity=1) "
     + " AND project.workflowmaxstatus='finish' " + " AND project.workflowminstatus='finish' "
     + " AND projectfile.type=1 AND projectfile.filename like '%." + format + "' AND project.startdate > NOW() - interval '" + month + " months' GROUP BY customer.id";
   LazyList<Customer> customerList = Customer.findBySQL(query);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you running a free form query from a model: `Customer.findBySQL(query)`.  The method [Model#findBySQL](http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/snapshot/org/javalite/activejdbc/Model.html#findBySQL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) does have limitations:

> Ensure that the query returns all columns associated with this model so that the resulting models could hydrate themselves properly....

You simply cannot use such query from a model. What you need in this case  is [Base#findAll](http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/snapshot/org/javalite/activejdbc/Base.html#findAll(java.lang.String))  or [DB#findAll](http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/snapshot/org/javalite/activejdbc/DB.html#findAll(java.lang.String)).

tx